# Sharepoint DataSource in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, sharepoint-list, lightswitch-2013

is there any way to select customize columns from sharepointlist in lightswitch?

for example in PreprocessQuery Method

```
query =query.Select(x=> new Customer{Id=x.Id,FirstName=x.FirstName,LastName=x.LastName});
```

in this query `Id` is readonly
Property indexer 'Id' cannot assigned to -- it is read only

or when do not Select id in query in result select first customer

FirstName     LastName

Lucas         Ponzo

Lucas         Ponzo

Lucas         Ponzo

Lucas         Ponzo

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Not straight out of the box, no I'm afraid not. Lightswitch cannot return anonymous collections. It can only return a collection of your Lightswitch entities.

The only way to achieve what you want in Lightswitch is to use WCF RIA as you can create custom models and return them this way. Michael Washington has some excellent articles on it on his website [that can be found here](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/21/WCF-RIA-Service.aspx). Also, [this article](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx) will probably get you started though if you're using VS2013.

Hope that helps.

Paul.